# How to change the text No File Chosen and its position in the File Upload File in the Contact Form 7 plugin

Tags: file-upload, contact-form-7

Dear Stackoverflow Members,
I am using Contact Form 7 plugin for my WordPress website and try to customise the File Upload input.
I was able to change the 'Chose a File' button with this line of CSS code.

```
.wpcf7-file {
  color: transparent;
}
.wpcf7-file::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.wpcf7-file::after {
  content: 'Choisir un fichier';
  color: #FFF;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #286889;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  outline: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
    margin-top: 7px;
}
.wpcf7-file:active {
  outline: 0;
}
.wpcf7-file:active::after {
  background-color: #ff9800; 
}
```

However, I really do not understand how to change the text and the position of the placeholder 'No File Chosen' who is still in the middle of the input as you can see on the below image.

[image: File Upload input]

Any help would be very nice.

PS: in French, 'No File Chosen' is 'Aucun fichier choisi'

Comment: You cannot, File upload fields are controlled by the browser, and therefore not customisable.  If you want more control over a file upload field, you will need to use a plugin which uploads files using javascript rather than the default browser POST method.  Here is a [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/drag-and-drop-multiple-file-upload-contact-form-7/) for cf7 forms, but I have not used it so you will need to test it to see how customisable it is.

Comment: Dear @Aurovrata. Thank you very much for your kind response. I will then try the Drag and Drop Multiple File Upload – Contact Form 7 that you mentioned. Thank you.